# How do I fix my .desktop files in /usr/share/applications?

Tags: nautilus, .desktop

I don't want to go too deeply into the issue, but I deleted some of the Nautilus-related `.desktops` in `/usr/share/applications`. What all should I have in the folder? I have:

```
nautilus-autorun-software.desktop
nautilus.desktop~
nautilus-folder-handler (copy).desktop
nautilus-folder-handler (copy).desktop~
nautilus-folder-handler.desktop~
nautilus-home.desktop~
```

My reason for asking is that my biggest problem occurs when using the dash search. If I search for "Documents", "Videos", etc. folders, they are unclickable. I think I may have broken something related to these files. Any help?

---

Edit: I used my LiveUSB, copied the Nautilus-related files to my install, and now it works. However, I have another problem with my dash search:

[image]

I have 2 "Downloads"... both work, but having two kind of bugs me. Any ideas?

Comment: *"...in this folder"* What is 'this folder'?

Comment: I guess /usr/share/applications - as the title says.

Comment: Did your second problem appear before? Otherwise you could check */usr/share/applications* for duplicates/double entries, possibly this helps.

Comment: I have 165 items in that folder, you must have deleted quite a few. Can you try deleting one of the 'Downloads' folders, you probably imported a dupe from the Live USB? Also, check that .local/share/applications (in the /home folder) doesn't have your duplicate Downloads folder. *EDIT*You should probably make sure you have a good backup of your important files before you go changing stuff like this. Do that first, then troubleshoot and delete, etc.

Comment: I made the mistake of editing the Home Folder .desktop in the root folder and NOT copying it to .local/share/applications...I was adding some quicklists to my Home Folder icon. But yes, backing up is always the way to go :) A caveat to others.

I checked the .local.... folder and there is no Downloads.desktop. And, now I have 3 Home Folders when I search.... =/ I know the one is in .local... and the one should be in /usr/share/applications, but why 3? I'll look more into this...

Comment: Ok...I had a few duplicates of Home Folder all over the place...deleted what wasn't needed and now I have one. I think I can live with the double Downloads. Thank you all for your help! You all are awesome here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(OP solved issue)*

I made the mistake of editing the Home Folder .desktop in the root folder and NOT copying it to `~/.local/share/applications`... I was adding some quicklists to my Home Folder icon. But yes, backing up is always the way to go :) A caveat to others. I checked the `.local....` folder and there is no Downloads.desktop. And, now I have 3 Home Folders when I search.... =/ I know the one is in .local... and the one should be in `/usr/share/applications`, but why 3? I'll look more into this... – Ryan McClure Feb 23 at 10:10

I had a few duplicates of Home Folder all over the place... deleted what wasn't needed and now I have one. I think I can live with the double Downloads. Thank you all for your help! You all are awesome here. – Ryan McClure Feb 23 at 10:22